# macOS Catalina takes 60 seconds to launch applications on bad wifi

Tags: mac-osx

I was forced to upgrade to Catalina to get some software working with the [new notarization system](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=09032019a).  I have a problem that I'm sure is caused by that same system.  I commute on trains, where the wifi is patchy, and I believe it also does various traffic shaping/rate limiting.  If I'm on this wifi then various command-line applications will take 61-63 seconds to launch, such as:

- Maven
- GHC (Haskell compiler)
- New binaries generated by clang

I'm fairly certain by now that there is a 60 second timeout in the notarization-checking system that is trying to connect to a central server.  At the end of the 60 seconds I believe I see a very brief flash of the notarization dialog.  I can reproduce the 60 seconds delay several times in a row, but then if I turn my wifi off, say 10 seconds in to the delay, the application will instantly launch, so it's clearly network related.  It doesn't happen on other connections or with the wifi off.

So my question is: what can I do about this?  I'll take any solutions: reducing the time-out, turning off the checks, blocking IP access to the server, etc etc, although I would prefer something I can easily reverse when I need to test notarization of my own software.

Comment: What do you see if you run `tcpdump` against your WiFi interface? I would expect that to show you what server/IP address your machine is trying to reach out to.

Comment: When I run a.out after clang, it looks like it contacts 17.248.144.181, which dig -x says resolves to nserver.apple.com. hostmaster.apple.com.

Comment: If you add an entry to `/etc/hosts` resolving `nserver.apple.com` to `127.0.0.1` and/or `::1`, does that help? You can then comment out the entry (and possibly flush the DNS cache) when you want it to work properly.

Comment: Had to wait for commute home... tried editing /etc/hosts and flushing cache. The delay increased from 1 minute to around 2 minutes but is now much more variable. tcpdump showed it still contacting some servers in 17.248 subnet, though not immediately. Perhaps it's using some fallback servers or a different DNS lookup to lookup those servers.

Comment: Yes, you might have to work out what DNS records are used, (`tcpdump` can help here too). It does seem like a bit of a flaw with this new service if it’s going to try and phone home every time an app is launched